# Why/how is everything $() based in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know a bit of JavaScript, and can work fine with jQuery. I just don't get why everything is referenced from `$()`. My understanding is that `$` is never needed in JavaScript (unlike for example PHP, where every variable is prefixed with `$)`.

I've looked through the source code, and it doesn't really make sense. Is it just that `$` is the function name (for example, it could have easily have been `jQuery()`, but they selected `$?`) I assume not, though, as I don't think `$` is valid in function names in JavaScript?

Answer (score 18):

`$` is just a global variable that's also a reference to the jQuery function, it's `$` on purpose so it's less to type. `$` is perfectly valid for a function name in ECMAScript:

```
function $(){}; alert(typeof $);
```

Note that if you're using multiple libraries you can use function scope to avoid clashing dollar sign variables, eg:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){ 
    $('body').hide();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6):

`$()` is the same as `jQuery()`. Also, `$` is a valid function name.